# Can't get to exif data .JPG image

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to read the exif data from a .JPG image. I've tried differents solutions found here and there (PIL, piexif, exifread...) and none of them worked for this set of images. It worked for other images taken from another camera but not for this one, all these different methods returning empty dictionaries. It seems that there is no exif data but (I apologies for my newbyness) when I RIGHT-click + properties (I use windows), I do see what is exif data to me : date of creation, etc...

Here is one image :
[image.JPG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tdm1E.jpg)

If another of the thousands of anonymous heroes could help me on this one, I would be very grateful...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright so I found a solution which I share now.
The problem is that the libraries that open metadata are not taking all possible configurations for the image file and therefore, they can handle some and some others they cannot. I finally made it using exiftool, an executable that I dowloaded on my windows on this link :
https://sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/

Then I paste the executable in a folder and I add exiftool.py in that folder, that I got from :
https://github.com/smarnach/pyexiftool/find/master

Then, using this small piece of code (for example):

```
import exiftool
with exiftool.ExifTool("exiftool.exe") as et:
    metadata = et.get_metadata_batch(files)
for d in metadata:
    print("{:20.20} {:20.20}".format(d["SourceFile"],
                                     d["File:FileCreateDate"]))
```

Of course, this is just to show that you indeed can access the metadata, then you can do whatever you want with that. Here is the documentation of the library exiftool : http://smarnach.github.io/pyexiftool/

Cheers, JM

Comment: Note that FileCreateDate is the filesystem creation date/time.  The file you posted contains no embedded metadata other than JFIF resolution information (no date/times).